# LayerSwitcher with sidebar, how to compress groups from radio buttons?

Tags: openlayers

I use openlayers and LayerSwitcher with sidebar (https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher)

Code:

```
var mapAtt = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Layers',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Group1',
                    fold: 'open',
                    layers: [
                        vectorLayer1,
               vectorLayer2
                    ]
                }),
                new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Group2',
                    fold: 'open',
                    layers: [
                        vectorLayer3,
                vectorLayer4
                    ]
                }),

                new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Group3',
                    fold: 'open',
                    layers: [
                        vectorLayer5,
                   ]
                })

            ]
        })


var sidebar = new ol.control.Sidebar({ element: 'sidebar', position: 'left' });
var toc = document.getElementById("layers");
ol.control.LayerSwitcher.renderPanel(mapAtt, toc);
mapAtt.addControl(sidebar);
```

Result legend:

[image]

I want to insert in the sidebar a radio button to select (click) the corresponding layer groups.

[image]

Selected group must be expanded, the rest collapsed.

What can i do activate and deactivate the layers from the radio button?

Answer (score 2):

Radio buttons are displayed for base layers (`type: 'base'`).
To hide the layers in the groups use `combine: true`.

```
        layers: [

            new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Select Group1',
                type: 'base',
                combine: true,
                layers: [
                    vectorLayer1,
                    vectorLayer2
                ]
            }),
            new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Select Group2',
                type: 'base',
                combine: true,
                layers: [
                    vectorLayer3,
                    vectorLayer4
                ]
            }),

            new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Select Group3',
                type: 'base',
                combine: true,
                layers: [
                    vectorLayer5,
               ]
            })

        ]
```